Configure Strapi's default rich text editor toolbar to hide few options
I want a stripped down version of the default rich text editor in strapi.
so that I can hide few options in the toolbar, particularly any media uploads.
I don't want to use any 3rd party plugin so have ruled out ck_editor which does give this functionality.
is there any way to configure the editors toolbar or extend the default editor and modify it?
